# PHP 5.3.8 startup warning

Tags: php

How do I solve my PHP startup warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions 
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imap.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on 
 line  0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions 
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-  
20090626/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in   
Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions 
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts- 
20090626/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in  
Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts- 
20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in 
Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib
/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions  
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-
20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in 
Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions
/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-  
20090626/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in 
Unknown on line 0
```

I've many configuration files in my config folder, I don't know where they come from:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/gd.ini on  
line 1 in Unknown on line 0 
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/gd.ini on 
line 2 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/imap.ini 
on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini 
on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d  
/memcache.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d 
/mysql.ini   
on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d 
/mysqli.ini  
on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/pdo.ini    
on   line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d  
/pdo_mysql.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/xcache.ini 
on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/conf.d/xcache.ini 
on line 9 in Unknown on line 0
```

Because of the warning I think I don't need them?

Comment: What diagnostic efforts have you made already?
Do those files exist? Have you found which php config file or section is loading them?

Comment: I've update my question. can I remove those configuration files? My PHP is working, and what is susohin, mysql_pdo, mysql_cli, etc.?

Comment: mysql_pdo, mysql_cli etc are extensions for PHP. MySQL_pdo allows you to use the PDO class to connect to mysql databases. IMAP.so allows you to connect to IMAP servers via PHP. If you are sure applications hosted on the server do not need these extensions, then you could try removing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_pdo` is the PHP Data Objects extension used for creating prepared SQL statements. For `mysql_cli`, CLI stands for Command Line Interface. Instead of removing the config files, open each one and remove or change the comments that are generating warnings (comments begin with a `;` in php.ini)

As for the dynamic loading warnings, there is a directive in php.ini called [extension](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) and will look similar to the following: (This is for a Windows box, *nix will be slightly different)

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Notice how some are commented out - Your php.ini is attempting to dynamically load extensions that cannot be found. Either comment out the lines in the configuration file(s) that are loading the erroneous extensions, or find the missing files. You may need to modify the php.ini directive [extension_dir](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) if you determine that you have the extension files, but PHP is not "finding" them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the complete route to the modules in the files in the directory /etc/php.d/

for example the gd extension:
Y just modify this:

extension=gd.so

for this:

extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so

because the .so files are in /usr/lib64/modules

Answer (score 0):

comment out the lines in your php.ini file that are causing the errors like this:

`;extension=imap.so`

Likely native support has been enabled but the .ini is still trying to call the extensions explicitly, this should have no effect on php's functioning but should remove the errors.